# How to make parent link element same width as child image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I apply the bootstrap class `"center-block"` to an image it sets it to display:block and sets left and right margins to auto. This centers the image within `col-md-12`, however the entire width of the `col-md-12` is now clickable. Only the image should be clickable. Here is a jsfiddle to show you what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/vocL0a48/

```
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <!--START MERCHANT:merchant name Kitbag Ltd from affiliatewindow.com.-->
                  <a href="http://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=107075&v=686&q=66973&r=122617">
                      <img class="center-block" src="http://www.awin1.com/cshow.php?s=107075&v=686&q=66973&r=122617"
                          border="0">
                  </a>
                  <!--END MERCHANT:merchant name Kitbag Ltd from affiliatewindow.com-->

              </div>
              <!--col-md-12-->
          </div>
          <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--container-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine for me. Only image is clickable. Which browser you are using now?

or you can use like this. Instead of using `center-block` use `text-center` in parent `div`

```
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <!--START MERCHANT:merchant name Kitbag Ltd from affiliatewindow.com.-->
                  <a href="http://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=107075&v=686&q=66973&r=122617">
                      <img src="http://www.awin1.com/cshow.php?s=107075&v=686&q=66973&r=122617"
                          border="0"></a>
                  <!--END MERCHANT:merchant name Kitbag Ltd from affiliatewindow.com-->

              </div>
              <!--col-md-12-->
          </div>
          <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--container-->
```

Comment: Yes you are rite, in chrome there is an issue in that

Comment: Welcome chap have a great day